# i made dictionary, when i am typing word it says the word donot exist in dictionary,why?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

In this program i am making a dictionary.

When i run this program and enter `1` in the menu the program asks me to `search meaning`, but when i type the word `404`(which is in the dictionary) it says `Word donot exist in dictionary`. Where does this problem come from?

```
print("This is a dictioinary")
print("\t\t\tWelcome to Geek Translator Game")
dictionary={"404":"Message not found","googler":"person who seaches on google"}
choose=None
while(choose!=0):
    choose=input('''0.Exit
1.search meaning
2.Add Word
3.Replace meaning''')

if choose is 0:
    print("bye")
if choose is 1:
    word=input("Enter the word\n")
    if word in dictionary:
        meaning=dictionary[word]
        print(meaning)
    else:
        print("Word donot exist in dictionary")
if choose is 2:
    word=input("Enter the word\n")
    if word in dictionary:
        print("Word already exists in dictionary")
        print("Try replacing meaning by going in option 3")
    else:
        defination=input("Enter the defination")
        dictionary[word]=defination
if choose is 3:
    word=input("Enter the term\n")
    if word in dictinary:
        meaning=input("Enter the meaning\n")
        dictionary[word]=meaning
    else:
        print("This term donot exist in dictionary")
```

Comment: `input` in Python 2.x is really `eval(raw_input(...))`, so `word` is the number `404` (which *isn't* in `dictionary`) not the string `'404'` (which is). **Use `raw_input`.**

Comment: Also, you should be using `==` instead of `is` (you're testing for equality, not identity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input()` interprets user input as a *Python expression*. If you enter `404`, Python interprets that *as an integer*. Your dictionary, however, contains a *string*.

You'll have to enter `"404"` *with quotes* for this to work correctly. Your *better* option would be to use `raw_input()` instead, to get the raw input the user typed without it having to be formatted as a Python expression:

```
word = raw_input("Enter the word\n")
```

Do this everywhere you use `input()` now. For your user menu input, you should really use `int(raw_input("""menu text"""))` rather than `input()`. You might be interested in [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) to learn more about how to ask a user for specific input.

Next, you are using `is` to test user choices. That this works at all is a *coincidence*, as Python has interned small integers you are indeed getting the same `0` object over and over again and the `is` test works. For *almost all comparisons* you want to use `==` instead however:

```
if choose == 0:
    # ...
elif choose == 1:
    # etc.
```

Comment: thanks,
you cleared my 5-6 concepts in your 1 solution
you are a genius